# Package Access (Protected Modifier) in Java

Tags: java

Suppose I have a package:

```
package com.g00gle.car
```

and

```
package com.g00gle.car.stereo
```

Is it possible to have a class in com.g00gle.car to access a class member in com.google.car.stereo? (Assuming that class member is labeled protected).

The answer is no... (by default) but is there a way to circumvent that? I have an application that I want to cut into distinct chunks... and to do that, I create extensions of the package. What's discouraging is the loss of package private access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This need will be addressed in Java 7 with [superpackages](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/modules/superpackages.html).  Or at least it was going to be.  Everything about Java 7 is currently up in the air.

- [JSR 294: Improved Modularity Support for the Java Programming Language](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=294)

**Edit**

Thanks for the link from Peter Štibraný in the comments below.  [Mark Reinhold's blog](http://blogs.oracle.com/mr/entry/plan_b_details) indicates this has been moved to Java 8 for release sometime in 2012 (take both the release and the release *date* with a grain of salt).

Comment: Uh oh, looks like this might be woefully out of date.

Comment: Plan for upcoming java release is pretty clear now (http://blogs.oracle.com/mr/entry/plan_b_details). Superpackages and modules support is now planned for Java 8.

Comment: Thanks @Peter, do you have a link I can add to my question?

Comment: superpackages are part of JSR 294. See http://blogs.oracle.com/mr/entry/plan_b_details for details of what will be in Java 7 and 8. JSR 294 is planned for Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

You can throw in a method in com.google.car.[classname] that provides access to the protected member:

```
protected Member member;

...

public Member getMember(){
   return member;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but as the OP says you no longer have access restrictions...anybody can access that member.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am using reflection in Java. I am using the Field.set(obj, f) method which requires access to the field f in obj.